# Is it possible in Java to Invoke another class' main method and return to the invoking code?

Tags: java

```
public class A{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Main code
    }
}

public class B{
    void someMethod()
    {
        String[] args={};
        A.main();
        System.out.println("Back to someMethod()");
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this? I found a method of doing the same using reflection but that doesn't return to the invoking code either. I tried using `ProcessBuilder` to execute it in a separate process but I guess I was missing out something.

Comment: Did you try it? Of course it's possible, `main` is just another method.

Comment: You mentioned ProcessBuilder.  Are you trying to start a second instance of the program altogether?  Alternatively, are you trying to start a new program from within another?

Comment: I have to apologize here. My main() method has a call to System.exit() in the end and that's why it didn't return to the invoking code. I just noticed it. Guess that makes this a useless question.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your code already nearly does it - it's just not passing in the arguments:

```
String[] args = {};
A.main(args);
```

The `main` method is only "special" in terms of it being treated as an entry point. It's otherwise a perfectly normal method which can be called from other code with no problems. Of course you may run into problems if it's written in a way which *expects* it only to be called as an entry point (e.g. if it uses `System.exit`) but from a language perspective it's fine.

Comment: I want to return to someMethod() after executing main. Right now it doesn't.

Comment: @AswinParthasarathy: That would happen if the other `main()` terminates the program.  Don't do that.

Comment: @AswinParthasarathy: It will unless your code explicitly kills the JVM. But you haven't shown us that code.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Ah yes. I've already realized it's a stupid question. My class does exit and that's why it didn't return.

Comment: If you don't have any arguments I believe you can just pass null.

Comment: @Jabari: Well it depends on what `main` does. Unless it's written to *handle* `args` being null, it's very likely you'll end up with a `NullPointerException`, just like normal.

Comment: @Jon Skeet True!  In this case his A.main() method didn't mention messing with the args at all, so passing null would do no harm.  That said, passing empty args is definitely a safer solution.

Comment: Thanks for making this clear. But this begs the question: what if I'm trying to write a unit test for a method that does invoke `System.exit()`? This method has some expected side effects like writing a file, which is what the test should check.

Comment: @flow2k: You could potentially set the security manager to prevent System.exit from actually doing anything, but I don't have experience of that. I'd usually use dependency injection to abstract out the notion of "something that can exit the process" and have a fake implementation you can use in your tests.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can do call `A.main()`.

You can do this:

```
String[] args = {};
A.main(args);
```

If you don't care about the arguments, then you can do something like:

```
public static void main(String ... args)
```

and call it with:

```
A.main(); //no args here
```

Comment: Ya that was the problem. I didn't notice it had System.exit() in the end and that's why got confused and posted.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing magic about the name "main".  What you've sketched ought to work, so your problem must be something else.  Test my claim by changing the name of "main" to something
else, I bet it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can call `main` method like the way you have just asked but not the way you have done it. First, every execution process starts from the `main` method. So, if you want to do it the way you want you can do right this way. This code will execute `Hello! World` eight times:

```
class B
{
  B()
  {
    while(A.i<8)
    {
      String a[]={"Main","Checking"};
      A.main(a);
    }
    System.exit(0);
  }

}

class A
{
  public static int i=0;
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    System.out.println("Hello! World");
    i++;
    B ob=new B();
  }
}
```

`
The iteration part, you can leave it if you want.
I Hope I gave you the solution just the way you wanted. :)

Answer (score 1):

Of course.
    String[] args = {};
    A.main(args);

Just be aware: from purely what you have up there, the main method is still the entry point to the program.  Now, if you are trying to run the main method in a new PROCESS, this is a different story.