# how to restart a program upon meeting a condition in JAVA?

Tags: java

I am new to JAVA and am writing a JAVA code that computes the cost incurred by a patient.
If the user likes to calculate cost for another patient he enters "Y" on the prompt and the program needs to compute once more.

How do I call the main() for the program to re-run?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package demo;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author seshasai
 */
public class PatientHospital {

    public static void main(String[] args){
      double totalCost = 0;

      totalCost = costCalculator();
      System.out.println("totalCosts " + totalCost);
      tryAgain();


    }

    public static void tryAgain(){
         String tryAgain;
      System.out.println("Do you want to calculate cost for another patient (Y/N): ");
      Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
      tryAgain = in.next();
      if(tryAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
        main();

      }

    }

    public static double costCalculator(){
        System.out.println("Enter YES if it is a day charge, NO if it is night charge");
        Scanner i = new Scanner (System.in);
        double totalCost =0;
        String day = i.next();;

        if (day.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")){
             totalCost = dayCharges();


        }else if (day.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")){
            totalCost = overNightCharges();

        }
       return totalCost;

    }
    public static double overNightCharges(){
        Scanner i = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter overnight, medication and labcosts");
        double onCharges = i.nextDouble();
        double medication = i.nextDouble();
        double lab = i.nextDouble();

        double totalFees = onCharges + medication + lab;
        return totalFees;
    }

    public static double dayCharges(){
        Scanner i = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter medication and labcosts");

        double medication = i.nextDouble();
        double lab = i.nextDouble();

        double totalFees = medication + lab;
        return totalFees;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use a loop such as a while loop. Also please search on topics before asking as this has been asked here many times previously.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095839/is-it-possible-in-java-to-invoke-another-class-main-method-and-return-to-the-in look here you just need to call it like main(new String[]{});

Comment: @sascha10000: NO -- please don't recommend recursion where a simple while loop is all that is needed. That makes no sense in this situation -- he's not trying to call another class's main method here.

Comment: But this was his question. He only says he is new to java not new to programming therefore I think he may know the difference between recursion and loops. I wanted to answer his question but refer to the while approach, but you marked it as duplicate (which it totally is).

Comment: @sascha10000: His question was how to restart a program if the user enters an affirmative response, and the canonical answer is to use a while loop or better a do-while and check a sentinel value. If you have main call main you open a can of worms unnecessarily.

Comment: I don't really like the answer on the one this was marked as a duplicate of, so I'm going to suggest this here:

You should modify your `tryAgain` function to return a boolean value instead of void.  Make it true if you want to go again, and false if you want to quit.  Then modify your main to use a do-while loop so it looks like this (excuse formatting)
`      public static void main(String[] args){
do{
double totalCost = 0;

      totalCost = costCalculator();
      System.out.println("totalCosts " + totalCost);
      }while(tryAgain());
}
`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels you are totally right. But wouldn't it be nice to tell him why this is a very bad design choice... But you're right the answer to this question is using the while in my 10 yrs of experience I have never called the main explicitly and had never had it on my mind at all.