# 'Cannot find symbol - variable args' error when attempting to launch new class

Tags: java, user-interface, find, symbols, args

I am having an error while coding to 'jump' to another class. I have created a GUI, and added an ActionListener. I would like the program to go to another class (called 'Project2') when the 'button2' is clicked. However, when entering the code 'Project2.main(args);' in order to do so, I am given an error 'Cannot find symbol - variable args' .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 'Cannot find symbol - variable args' means that you are trying to use a variable, called 'args', which the compiler cannot find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Mike Nakis comment, you do not have a variable args to pass to the function main(), so create empty String array args and pass to main function. You can add argument strings to the array if needed. Therefore, change code to:

```
String[] args = {};//new line 
Project2.main(args);
```

[See related SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095839/is-it-possible-in-java-to-invoke-another-class-main-method-and-return-to-the-in)

Comment: Thank you, though I now have another error, saying that I must 'throw IOException'. I know how this works, though I'm not really sure on where to add this line.

Comment: If this has dealt with your original question then please tick as answer to help future SO members and then raise a new question about throwing the IOException which is new issue.